# Convert a String[] in C# to a Char *[] in C++

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, wrapper

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010.  This is my first time writing a wrapper for a C++ class.  The class in C++ looks like this:

```
bool exampleCode(char* arrayOfStrings[], int number, char* regularString)
```

I created the header file which looks like:

```
bool exampleCode(array<String^>^ arrayOfStrings, int number, String^ regularString)
```

and the .cpp file class looks like:

```
bool exampleCode(array<String^>^ arrayOfStrings, int number, System::String^ regularString)
```

I figured out how to marshal the regularString data but I'm not sure how to convert the `String` array into a `char*[]`.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the native function clean up the memory it's passed or does it leave that to the caller?

Comment: I believe the native function cleans up the memory it's passed but I'm not 100% since I'm new to C++/CLI programming.

Comment: Okay, then the next question is _how_ does the native function clean up the memory? `free`? `delete[]`? `CoTaskMemFree`? `LocalFree`? `GlobalFree`?

Comment: Actually nevermind, the native function does not delete the memory.  It appears that that is left up to the caller.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Last clarification before I post an answer: are you positive that `exampleCode` takes `char*` arguments and not `const char*`/`char const*` arguments? The possible presence of `const` changes the answer dramatically. Also, if the `const` really _isn't_ there, is it possible for the native function to modify its arguments, or is immutability assumed?

Comment: It does not appear to take a const char*.  The arrayOfStrings is a series of file names and the regularString is an output filename.

Comment: The native function seems to read the arrayOfStrings variable and loads its contents into a vector.  These contents are read and merged.  The regularString is the output file of the merge.  Yes, number represents the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easily reusable version (complete with demonstration) that improves on @ildjarn's answer by reducing the number of allocations and improving locality.  It also uses your choice of encoding such as UTF-8.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <windows.h>
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;

template <typename T>
struct advanced_marshal;

template <>
struct advanced_marshal<char*[]>
{
    char** get() { return &m_strings[0]; }

    advanced_marshal( array<System::String^>^ strings, UINT code_page = CP_ACP ) : m_strings(strings->Length)
    {
        if (int count = strings->Length) {
            int i;
            size_t total_length_estimate = count; // one NUL byte per string
            for( i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
                total_length_estimate += strings[i]->Length * 4;
            }

            m_buffer.resize(total_length_estimate);
            auto tail = m_buffer.begin(), end = m_buffer.end();
            i = 0;
            do {
                m_strings[i] = &*tail;
                pin_ptr<const WCHAR> pwsz = PtrToStringChars(strings[i]);
                tail += 1 + WideCharToMultiByte(code_page, 0, pwsz, strings[i]->Length, &*tail , end - tail, nullptr, nullptr);

                ++i;
            } while (i < count);
        }
    }

    advanced_marshal(advanced_marshal<char*[]>&& other) { m_buffer.swap(other.m_buffer); m_strings.swap(other.m_strings); }

private:
    advanced_marshal(const advanced_marshal<char*[]>&); // = delete
    void operator=(const advanced_marshal<char*[]>&); // = delete

    std::vector<char> m_buffer;
    std::vector<char*> m_strings;
};

void print_some_strings( char* strings[], int num )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < num; ++i )
        std::cout << strings[i] << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    print_some_strings(advanced_marshal<char*[]>(args).get(), args->Length);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is ideally efficient (minimal copying) and exception-safe:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using System::IntPtr;
using System::String;
using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

bool exampleCodeManaged(array<String^>^ arrayOfStrings, String^ regularString)
{
    auto deleter = [](char* p) { Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(p)); };
    typedef std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(deleter)> cstr_t;
    auto make_cstr = [&deleter](String^ s)
    {
        return cstr_t(
            static_cast<char*>(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s).ToPointer()),
            deleter
        );
    };

    std::vector<cstr_t> cstrs;
    cstrs.reserve(arrayOfStrings->Length);
    for each (String^ s in arrayOfStrings)
        cstrs.push_back(make_cstr(s));

    std::vector<char*> ptrs;
    ptrs.reserve(cstrs.size());
    std::for_each(
        cstrs.begin(),
        cstrs.end(),
        [&ptrs](cstr_t& cstr) { ptrs.push_back(cstr.get()); }
    );

    auto reg_cstr = make_cstr(regularString);

    return exampleCode(ptrs.data(), arrayOfStrings->Length, reg_cstr.get());
}
```

(Note that `number` does not need to be passed in to the managed function as it can be deduced from the array's length.)

Alternatively, incorporating Ben Voigt's suggestion to use `std::string` instead of the `Marshal` class:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

using System::String;

bool exampleCodeManaged(array<String^>^ arrayOfStrings, String^ regularString)
{
    using msclr::interop::marshal_as;

    std::vector<std::string> strs;
    strs.reserve(arrayOfStrings->Length);
    for each (String^ s in arrayOfStrings)
        strs.push_back(marshal_as<std::string>(s));

    std::vector<char*> ptrs;
    ptrs.reserve(strs.size());
    std::for_each(
        strs.begin(),
        strs.end(),
        [&ptrs](std::string& s) { ptrs.push_back(&s[0]); }
    );

    auto reg = marshal_as<std::string>(regularString);

    return exampleCode(ptrs.data(), arrayOfStrings->Length, &reg[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `StringToHGlobalAnsi` is "ideally efficient".  It does work, but I refuse to use it on principle, because its name is highly misleading -- it doesn't actually create an `HGLOBAL` and the result cannot be passed to `GlobalFree` (which is the usual deallocation function for `HGLOBAL`s).

Comment: @Ben : I'm not sure that it is either, but the easy alternatives were using `marshal_as<std::string>` or `marshal_as<char const*>` which would require an extra copy of the data unless `const_cast<>` is used, and all things considered, I'd rather avoid `const_cast<>`.

Comment: `std::string` is perfectly usable, just do `&s[0]`.  But I think I'd prefer a single `vector<char>`, filled in by calling [`Encoding::GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s1x2atd.aspx) (packing all strings end-to-end).  One allocation, automatic free, no custom deleter.

Comment: While trying to write that "preferred" version, I discovered that: (1) `Encoding::GetBytes` only accepts a `pin_ptr`, not an `interior_ptr`, and (2) it copies all the data on the way in AND out.  So decided not to use that after all.